# Hermitian form, fundamental $2$-form of Kahler structure on $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, kahler-manifolds

I've come across the following (it is an excerpt of Stolzenberg's lecture notes 19):

> Wirtinger's Inequality.
>
> Let $L$ be a complex linear space and let $M$ be a real
>   even-dimensional subspace. Let $H$ be a positive definite Hermitian
>   form on $L$ . Then $H = S + iA$ where $S$ is symmetric and $A$ is
>   alternating . Let $\{ m_1,...,m_{2k} \} $ be a basis of $M$ which is
>   orthonormal with respect to $S$ . Then $$ | A ^k ( m_1 , . . . , m_{2
> > k} ) | \le  k !$$ with equality holding precisely when $M$ is a
>   complex $k$-dimensional subspace of $L$ . (Here $A^k$ is the $k$-th
>   exterior power of $A$ .)
>
> By a suitable shuffling of the basis it can be arranged that $A ^k (
> > m_1 , . . . , m_{2 k} ) \ge 0$
>
> Let $z_1, . . . , z_n$ be coordinates on complex $n$ - space
>   $\mathbb{C}^n$ and set
>
> $$\omega = \frac{i}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n dz_j \wedge d \overline{z}_j$$
>
> This is the fundamental $2$-form of the standard Kahler structure on
>   $\mathbb{C}^n$ and  at each point $p \in \mathbb{C}^n$ $\omega_p$ is
>   the alternating part of the positive definite Hermetian form:
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^n dz_{j(p)} \cdot d \overline{z}_{j(p)}$$
>
> on the tangent space to $\mathbb{C}^n$  at $p$.
>
> Therefore , if $\mathcal{M}$ is any smoothn $2k$-dimensional manifold
>   immersed in $\mathbb{C}^ n$ , Wirtinger's Inequality implies
>   immediately that:
>
> $$\int_{\mathcal{M}} \frac{1}{k!} \omega ^k \le \int_{\mathcal{M}} 1 \ d
> > \mathcal{M} = \text{Volume} _{2k}(\mathcal{M})$$
>
> with equality is and only if $ \mathcal{M}$ is a complex
>   $k$-dimensional manifold.
>
> Also each $\frac{1}{k!} \omega ^k $ is an exact $2k$ form.

My questions are:

Could you explain to me how we use the fact that $\omega$ is the fundamental $2$-form of the standard Kahler structure on $\mathbb{C}^n$ to apply the Wirtinger inequality here?

Is this somehow connected to this  [Second fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) ?

Could you explain to me what the fundamental $2$-form of the standard Kahler structure is? Or recommend a good source in which I could read about it?

In [Werner Ballmann's Lectures on Kahler Manifolds](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.mpim-bonn.mpg.de%2Fhwbllmnn%2Farchiv%2Fkaehler0609.pdf&ei=KxgTVZjHIKS_ywOx-YKQDA&usg=AFQjCNG6iksMf_73Da2BdiD66-1bLVQKuA&sig2=_iejU2co4RpbCv8m9DceSA) the author defines the *associated Kahler form* (which I presume could be the same as the fundamental $2$-form) in this way:

> Let $M$ be a complex manifold with complex structure $J$ and
>   compatible Riemannian metric $g = < \cdot, \cdot > $  (so $<JX, JY>= < X, Y > $). 
>    The alternating $2$-form $\omega(X, Y ) := g(JX, Y )$ is
>   called the associated Kahler form. We say that $g$ is a Kahler metric
>   and if $\omega$ is closed, we say that $(M, g)$ is a Kahler manifold.

On page 48, the author states that we can

> view $TM$ together with $J$ as a complex vector bundle over $M$, and
>   let $h$ be a Hermitian metric on $TM$. Then $g = Re h$ is a compatible
>   metric on $M$ and $Imh$ is the associated Kahler form: 
>   $$g(JX, Y ) = \Re h(JX, Y ) = \Re h(iX, Y ) = \Re(−ih(X, Y )) = \Im h(X, Y )$$ If $g$ is a
>   compatible Riemannian metric on $M$ and $\omega$ is the associated
>   Kahler form, then $h = g + i\omega$ is a Hermitian metric on $TM$.

Also, a Riemannian metric is a general notion. Looking at what I've pasted into the frame above, do we need to consider Riemannian metrics compatible with the complex structure in general or not necessarily?

I would be very grateful for all your insight.

Comment: There are multiple questions in your post; I hope I've either: addressed them; given a sufficiently complete sketch that you can fill in missing details; or cited suitable references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Good sources for the material below include:

- R. O. Wells, *Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*.
- P. Griffiths and J. Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*.

The literature contains numerous conventions about factorials in wedge products, signs, and factors of two. I've tried to be internally consistent, but there always remains the possibility of errors.

---

Let $\Cpx^{n}$ have complex coordinates $z_{j} = x_{j} + iy_{j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$, let $\bar{z}_{j} = x_{j} - iy_{j}$, and note that for each $j$ we have
\begin{align*}
dz_{j} \otimes d\bar{z}_{j}
  &= (dx_{j} + i\, dy_{j}) \otimes (dx_{j} - i\, dy_{j}) \\
  &= (dx_{j} \otimes dx_{j} + dy_{j} \otimes dy_{j})
   - i (dx_{j} \otimes dy_{j} - dy_{j} \otimes dx_{j}) \\
  &= (dx_{j} \otimes dx_{j} + dy_{j} \otimes dy_{j})
   - 2i dx_{j} \wedge dy_{j}.
\end{align*}
That is, if
$$
H = \sum_{j=1}^{n} dz_{j} \otimes d\bar{z}_{j} = g - 2i\omega,
$$
then $g$ is the Euclidean inner product on $\Cpx^{n} \simeq \Reals^{2n}$ and $\omega$ is the standard symplectic form:
$$
g = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (dx_{j} \otimes dx_{j} + dy_{j} \otimes dy_{j}),\qquad
\omega = \sum_{j=1}^{n} dx_{j} \wedge dy_{j}.
\tag{1}
$$
(The pairing $H$ is Hermitian, i.e., is complex linear in the first argument, and satisfies $H(Y, X) = \overline{H(X, Y)}$ for all $X$ and $Y$ in $\Cpx^{n}$. The latter encodes symmetry of the real part of $H$ and skew-symmetry of the imaginary part of $H$.)

Note also that
$$
d\mu
  = \frac{\omega^{k}}{k!}
  = dx_{1} \wedge dy_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{n} \wedge dy_{n}
$$
is the Euclidean volume form of $\Cpx^{n}$. That is, the answer to the first question is that the top exterior power of the imaginary part of the standard Hermitian structure on $\Cpx^{n}$ is the Euclidean volume form on $\Cpx^{n} \simeq \Reals^{2n}$. (Caution: Some authors define the volume form to be $dx_{1} \wedge \dots dx_{n} \wedge dy_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge dy_{n} = (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\, d\mu$.)

Let $M$ is a smooth, immersed, oriented $2k$-manifold in $\Cpx^{n}$. The integral
$$
\int_{M} \frac{\omega^{k}}{k!}
$$
can be evaluated using a partition of unity $\{\rho_{\alpha}\}$ subordinate to a cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ by coordinate neighborhoods. In each open set $U_{\alpha}$ of the cover, let $\{\dd_{1}, \dots, \dd_{2k}\}$ denote the Euclidean coordinate frame (in the ordering compatible with the volume form convention above, and suppressing the dependence on $\alpha$). If $dV$ denotes the Euclidean volume form on $\Cpx^{k}$ and $\phi_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha} \to M$ is the inverse of the chart mapping to $U_{\alpha}$, then Wirtinger's inequality applied to the $2$-form $A = \phi_{\alpha}^{*} \omega$ on $U_{\alpha}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{M} \frac{\omega^{k}}{k!}
  &= \sum_{\alpha} \int_{M} \rho_{\alpha}\, \frac{\omega^{k}}{k!} \\
  &= \sum_{\alpha} \rho_{\alpha}\, \int_{U_{\alpha}} \phi_{\alpha}^{*}\frac{\omega^{k}}{k!} \\
  &= \sum_{\alpha} \rho_{\alpha}\, \int_{U_{\alpha}} \phi_{\alpha}^{*}\frac{\omega^{k}(\dd_{1}, \dots, \dd_{2k})}{k!}\, dV \\
  &\leq \sum_{\alpha} \rho_{\alpha}\, \int_{U_{\alpha}} dV \\
  &= \sum_{\alpha} \rho_{\alpha}\, \operatorname{Vol}(U_{\alpha})
   = \operatorname{Vol}(M),
\end{align*}
with equality if and only if $T_{p}M$ is a complex subspace of $T_{p}\Cpx^{n}$ at each point, i.e., if $M$ is an immersed *complex* submanifold of $\Cpx^{n}$.

To address the questions about Ballmann's notes, let $(M, J, g)$ be a complex manifold equipped with a complex structure $J$ and a $J$-compatible Riemannian matric $g$. The $2$-tensor $\omega$ defined by $\omega(X, Y) = g(JX, Y)$ is skew-symmetric since
$$
\omega(Y, X) = g(JY, X) = g(JJY, JX) = g(-Y, JX) = -g(JX, Y) = -\omega(X, Y).
\tag{2}
$$

Moreover, the complexified tangent bundle of $M$, $TM \otimes \Cpx$, splits into eigenbundles of $J$, i.e., into sub-bundles of $(1, 0)$- and $(0, 1)$-vectors. If $X$ is a tangent vector to $M$, define complex vectors
$$
X^{(1, 0)} = \tfrac{1}{2}(X - iJX),\qquad
X^{(0, 1)} = \tfrac{1}{2}(X + iJX).
$$
It's easy to check that $X = X^{(1, 0)} + X^{(0, 1)}$, that $J(X^{(1, 0)}) = iX^{(1, 0)}$, and that $J(X^{(0, 1)}) = -iX^{(0, 1)}$.

The complex vector bundle $(TM, J)$ is isomorphic to the complex vector bundle $(T^{(1, 0)}M, i)$ under the mapping $X \mapsto X^{(1, 0)}$. The Riemannian metric extends uniquely to a *complex bilinear* pairing $H$ on $TM \otimes \Cpx$. Since
$$
H(X, Y) = g(X, Y) = H(JX, JY),\qquad
H(JX, Y) = g(JX, Y) = \omega(X, Y) = -H(JY, X),
$$
equation (2) implies the Hermitian metric $h$ defined by $h(X, Y) = 2H(X^{(1, 0)}, \overline{Y^{(1, 0)}})$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
h(X, Y)
   = 2H(X^{(1, 0)}, Y^{(0, 1)})
  &= \tfrac{1}{2} H(X - iJX, Y + iJY) \\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl(H(X, Y) + H(JX, JY) - iH(JX, Y) + iH(X, JY)\bigr) \\
  &= g(X, Y) - i \omega(X, Y).
\end{align*}

It's meaningful to consider Riemannian metrics not compatible with a complex structure $J$, but:

- The preceding algebraic yoga only works out nicely if $g$ is $J$-compatible;
- If $g_{0}$ is an arbitrary Riemannian metric, then
  $$
  g(X, Y) = \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl(g_{0}(X, Y) + g_{0}(JX, JY)\bigr)
  $$
  (the resulting of averaging $g_{0}$ over the action of $J$) is $J$-compatible. That is, assuming $J$-compatibility is not especially intrusive.